# Are questions about cron topical for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are currently 18,193 questions on Stack Overflow with the [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) tag. Are questions about cron/crontab topical for Stack Overflow, or should they be redirected to another site such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)? (Both sites have their own [cron] tags with a fair number of existing questions.)

A weak argument in favor of keeping them on Stack Overflow is that cron implements a tiny programming language. A stronger argument IMHO is sheer inertia. The counterargument is that such questions are about using software, not about writing it.

Comment: I think questions about using the cron-syntax in a programming language is on topic. E.g. using *spring-scheduling* with cron expressions for Java

Comment: A good indicator of wrong site: if canonical answer to the problem is located on another site.

Comment: Unix is designed to blend the boundary between user and programmer. Mistakes will be made.

Answer (score 60):

IMHO, calling crontab syntax a programming language makes a mockery of the term. By that logic, almost any configuration file would be considered a programming language (e.g. `/etc/passwd` is effectively `switch` statements saying what shell to run based on the login username). I've frequently referred questions about things like `iptables` rules to unix.stackexchange.com, but they have more right to be called programming than `crontab` lines.

I don't think the sheer number of questions is an indicator that they're appropriate.

- Many of the thousands of [cron] questions are old (particularly the ones with many upvotes), and may predate the creation of the other Stack Exchange sites.
- Some of the questions with the [cron] tag are not even about `cron`. They added the tag because they happened to be using `cron` to run the program that the question is really about.

Legitimate SO questions about `cron` should relate to how to write programs that are run using it, not the basic process of using `cron`. A good example of this is [How to simulate the environment cron executes a script with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with). Other appropriate questions are about writing programs that interact with `cron`, e.g. [How can I programmatically create a new cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job)

Admittedly the boundaries between these 3 sites has always been a bit fuzzy. But I think if your question is just about how to fill in the first 5 fields of a `crontab` entry, or "why isn't my cron job running?", it's not really a programming question and doesn't belong on SO.

Just this side of the SO boundary are questions about doing tricky scheduling that isn't directly supported by the crontab syntax, e.g. "first Monday of every month". This usually involves adding code to the script that's run from the crontab, so it slips into the programming world and is on-topic.

Comment: I agree here. Most questions are of the type _My cron does not work_, which by default is answered by [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651). If that does not answer the question, it is a shell script problem. There are however a handful of interesting questions which do belong on SO. Two are already mentioned above, others I consider useful are questions of the form _How do setup crontab to schedule something in a way it is not designed to do_ (Eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724316) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48417100/8344060))

Comment: @kvantour Thanks, I've updated the answer to mention those kinds of questions.

Comment: As an asdie, the SO [cron wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) is fantastic and covers many common problems (different environment, `%` escaping, debugging strategies...)

Comment: Quite true, I was looking there to see if it answered this question. It doesn't, but it's practically a canonical answer all by itself.

Comment: A good rule of thumb: if you can remove cron of the question and the issue stays, it's not a cron question.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, the [written policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically allows questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers." Cron is definitely a software tool commonly used by programmers. OTOH, if there's consensus that cron questions are off topic, isn't that a sign that the policy should be revised to be more precise?

Comment: @senderle Windows is also a tool commonly used by programmers, that doesn't make generic WIndows question on topic. There's a "and is a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**" which actually defines the scope of the site.

Comment: @Braiam Isn't the analogy to Windows kind of a stretch here? It's true that cron solves problems that are not strictly unique to software development, but almost every professional developer I know has needed to learn the basics of cron at some point in the course of their programming work. To me the real question is whether migrating / redirecting cron questions is going to serve the needs of software developers who use Stack Overflow. I don't know the answer to that for sure, but it certainly doesn't seem cut-and-dry to me.

Comment: @senderle nope, it's the correct analogy since your statement is _open ended_, it has no limits. Only when accompanied with the conditional it has boundaries. That's why there has been several discussions about excel, word, vim, etc. The tool by itself doesn't mean it is automatically on topic, a tool plus tasks does (sometimes the task itself is enough, but it has to be practical).

Comment: @senderle if you want to frame it into the cron topic: is cron by itself enough to be on topic? No. Using crontab to edit a file is squarely a system administrator task. Using an api/library to install a cron task (ie. [debian cron debhelper](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dh_installcron.1.html) which is a software developer task, in the way it packages the software it develops) may be.

Comment: @Braiam you can infer boundaries from the functional scope of the program under consideration. The scope of Windows is much larger than the scope of cron. So I disagree that unqualified statements about the topicality of Windows questions and cron questions are equally open-ended.

Comment: @senderle again, you are missing the point. The task sets the scope, not the tool. A site for programmers, have no place for not programming questions.

Comment: @senderle, umh, what does a programmer/software developer need cron for? A sysadmin, surely (and they often need some programming skills too), but just for software development? Or are we talking something like scheduling nightly builds or taking backups? Though they'd still seem to sysadmin tasks, even if relevant to software development.

Comment: Put another way: A programmer using cron to run one of his programming tasks on a schedule is no different from a non-programmer running some other task on a schedule. If the answer is the same for a programmer and non-programmer, it's not programming-related. @senderle

Comment: Programmers frequently need to delete files, but that doesn't make questions about the `rm` command on-topic.

Comment: Fundamentally we are disagreeing on the very point of this site, I think. Which is fine. I'll move on.

Comment: So.. none of you set up a cronjob to notify you to check up and put a comment on this thread? Incidentally.. was that because you were reluctant to post a Question about how to do it?

Comment: @ilkkachu I see I need to work harder on my jokes.. :)

Comment: @Scratte, sorry. it's the text-only communication and the associated lack of tone and such context. :)

Answer (score 7):

As other have mentioned, there are questions that can be on-topic and off-topic with the tag `cron`. So it might be reasonable for it to stay.

However, I would like to add that even if it weren't getting it burinated (or removed from the site) is unlikely, since there are over 18,000 questions. As [rene has said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/10957435) (or perhaps some other editor. I didn't look through all 50+ revisions to see who exactly added this exact language):

> Be realistic
>
> If a tag has more than 1000 questions, the review work you and the community have to complete is enormous. You would need to fulfill the additional criterion:

We would need to prove it's causing a lot of extra harm, such as attracting more off-topic questions than on-topic. I'm not sure that case has been made yet. However, that certainly doesn't mean it can't be made in the future.

Comment: I don't think he was suggesting burninating the tag. His question was prompted by me voting to close a cron question as off-topic.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed. I actually don't have an opinion one way or the other.

Answer (score 4):

When looking at the questions, I find that some of them could well be migrated to ServerFault, but many - perhaps most - are about cron-related automation with additional programming aspects.

Examples:

- [Execute a job using Quartz API for a specific duration and random intervals of the hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434847/execute-a-job-using-quartz-api-for-a-specific-duration-and-random-intervals-of-t)
- [Persist data in JSON file from a cron job in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456548/persist-data-in-json-file-from-a-cron-job-in-node)
- [Stopping and starting execution of cron-job-manager (node-cron) upon condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63495074/stopping-and-starting-execution-of-cron-job-manager-node-cron-upon-condition)

so I don't think you can generalize. More active migration off site for the properly cron-only questions sounds like a right thing to do.

Comment: The second question you linked to isn't about `cron` at all.

Comment: @IInspectable: Well, it's tagged cron and has cron in the title and was one of the newest cron questions. Regardless, even if that's the case - that also demonstrates my point.

Comment: I was under the impression, that the point you were trying to make is, that certain questions about `cron` were on-topic. Picking a question that's on-topic, but isn't about `cron` doesn't seem to support the idea, that some `cron` questions are on-topic.

Comment: @IInspectable: The idea is that many/most cron questions don't fit the characterization by OP; and that they should not be redirected to another site. Mis-tagged questions are also an example of that, even if not exactly the one I brought up.

Comment: The question is whether questions about cron belong on SO, not specifically about the [cron] tag. The tag is just an easy way to find questions that fit the discussion, although there are also false positives.